# Fix string based on character mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text to display in HTML,for example :
`var htmlStr = "1.first thing %10-15%. 2.second thing %25-44%. 3.third`"

And i display it in div:

```
  $('#div1').html(htmlStr);
```

but when I display it in a `DIV1` in `HTML5` on mobile phone I get the next thing:

```
1.first thing %10-15.2%.second thing %25-44.3%.third
```

**(the mistake is : 15% - 15.2%)**

Its happens in the `iOS` system,How can I using `JavaScrip/jQuery` fix it based on this rule?

Comment: can you please format your question properly? also html code might be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: Where do those `(15% - 15.2%)` in the second line come from? Or is that the question?

Comment: Is there some form of templating involved here?

Comment: Please show us how exactly you "*display the text in a HTML5 div on device*". Code examples appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question guys...the (15%-12.2%) its just the mistake explain... to display the text I use jQuery ('#div1').html(htmlStr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `&#37;` instead of `%`.